# includes function doesn't recognize substring in text variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a "title" attribute to HTML td elements based on their text.

I have written the following:

```
$("tr.sel-rtac-first td:first-child").each(function(t,x){
    var hours = "";
    var text = $(x).text();
    switch (text) {
        case (text.includes("מרכזית-מדף פתוח") == true):
            hours = "יהדות 401: א - ה  08:00 - 19:00"
            break;
        default: hours = "text"
    }
    $(x).attr("title",hours);
});
```

I can see in my tests that the text variable is receiving the correct text:

```
"
                        Cen.lib-Stacks - מרכזית-מדף פתוח -#Four weeks - ארבעה שבועות#
                    "
```

The text is in Hebrew, but you can clearly see that the text I am looking for is indeed part of the variable text.
Yet it reverts to the default, not recognizing that the text includes that segment.

I also tried without the == ture in the code:

```
case (text.includes("מרכזית-מדף פתוח")):
```

But this doesn't work either.

A previous solution I tested was to use the .title() function, but that didn't work either (I suspect because the element doesn't have a title attribute to begin with, I am adding one).

How can I make sure that the includes function recognizes that the substring is indeed in the text?

Comment: It looks like you'd want an `if {} else {}` instead of `switch`. You're switching based on the text string, and the first case, while it evaluates to true, then says basically does the string `text` match the boolean `true`, which it doesn't so it fails. You want something like `if(text.includes("מרכזית-מדף פתוח")) { hours = "19:00 - 08:00 ... "; } else { hours = "text"; }`

Comment: Have you tried it with a plain if else statement, rather than the two case switch statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if` statement instead of a switch case as @mark.hch suggested.

Concerning the buggy includes, the issue can't be reproduced with the code you provided:

```js
const haystack = 'Cen.lib-Stacks - מרכזית-מדף פתוח -#Four weeks - ארבעה שבועות#';
const needle = 'מרכזית-מדף פתוח';
console.log(haystack.includes(needle));
```

The error you're observing is likely to be stemming from elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid if else statements, since this is just a test run and the actual code will include A LOT of cases, but it seems there is no choice.

Comment: The if else statements work.
I guess there are no easy solutions.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's your use of ´switch´ and ´case´ that is not good.

You can just write:

```
$("tr.sel-rtac-first td:first-child").each(function(t,x){
 var hours = "";
 var text = $(x).text();

 if (text && text.includes("מרכזית-מדף פתוח")) {
   hours = "יהדות 401: א - ה  08:00 - 19:00";
 } else {
   hours = "text";
 }

 $(x).attr("title",hours);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this type of search is RegExp with the unicode flag: `u`:

> ```
> // RegEx literal syntax for unicode ex. a => U+61 => \u{61}
>   /\u{5DE}\u{5E8}\u{5DB}\u{5D6}\u{5D9}\u{5EA}\x2D\u{5DE}\u{5D3}\u{5E3} \u{5E4}\u{5EA}\u{5D5}\u{5D7}/u
> ```

When I attempted to highlight certain letters the Stack editor would skip over them. To avoid any incompatibilities derived from different languages unicode is a possible solution. Translation was possible by using the [ES2015 Unicode regular expression transpiler](https://mothereff.in/regexpu).

In addition to the above suggestion -- the jQuery logic needs to be addressed:

- When using `.each()` method and referencing the current element, use `$(this)`

  ```
  var text = $(this).text()
  ```
- Methods such as `.includes()` and `.test()` (the Regexp method in demo) returns `true` or `false`. The less verbose syntax when in a condition is:

  ```
  if (RegExp.test("String")) {...
  ```

  Using `== true` will yield the same result but in other circumstances it can change type so be careful.

```js
$("tr td:first-child").each(function(){
  var text = $(this).text();
  if (/\u{5DE}\u{5E8}\u{5DB}\u{5D6}\u{5D9}\u{5EA}\x2D\u{5DE}\u{5D3}\u{5E3} \u{5E4}\u{5EA}\u{5D5}\u{5D7}/u.test(text)) {
    $(this).attr("title", "יהדות 401: א - ה  08:00 - 19:00");
  } else {
    $(this).attr('title', text);
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 5vh auto
}

td {
  width: 33%;
}

table, td {
  border: 1px solid #000
}

td::before {
  content: ' ';
  min-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Cen.lib-Stacks - מרכזית-מדף פתוח -#Four weeks - 
ארבעה שבועות#</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Cen.lib-Stacks - מרכזית-מדף פתוח -#Four weeks - 
ארבעה שבועות#</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Cen.lib-Stacks - מרכזית-מדף פתוח -#Four weeks - 
ארבעה שבועות#</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>TEST</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```